# Codeigniter allow .php file uploads

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codigniters built in file upload library, and I want to allow php files to be uploaded.

This facility is only available to admin users behind a secure login etc.

But for some reason, I am getting 'The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed' errors.

I have this in my controller:

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|doc|docx|php';
```

And I also have this line in config/mimes.php:

```
'php'   =>  'application/x-httpd-php',
```

This actualy functionality works if i try to upload an image file etc, so it is working, just not allowing .php files.

Any ideas why this doesnt work? Am i missing something?

Comment: Allowed type looks fine.. try to use this $config['allowed_types'] = '*';

Comment: Nope, still getting the same error?

Comment: Chk yur config.php file in config folder is it available in this file to?

Comment: I dont see any options for file types in the config file?

Comment: It even works with .html files. Just not PHP....WTF?

Comment: Is it possible that the files mime_type is being read as `text/plain`?

Comment: How would i even check for that?

Comment: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userfile"; filename="index.php"
Content-Type: text/php

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!!

When i looked at posted data, the mime type was Content-Type: text/php

But the corresponding mime type in mime.php was:

```
'php'   =>  'application/x-httpd-php',
```

So i changed it to:

```
'php'   =>  array('application/x-httpd-php', 'text/php'),
```

And it worked.

hallelujah!!