# Why I'm getting this error: The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

```
public function addAppdetails()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('appname', 'App Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('platform', 'Platform', 'required');
        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('category','App Category','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'App Description', 'required');
        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('app_pic','App Pic','required');
        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('file','App File','required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $appname = $this->input->post('appname');
            $platform = $this->input->post('platform');
            $category1 = $this->input->post('category');
            $descripton = $this->input->post('description');
            $category = implode(",", $category1);
            $data = array('name' => $appname, 'platform' => $platform, 'description' => $descripton, 'category' => $category);
            $this->appImageupload();
            die;
            $this->Dev_model->addApp($data);


        } else {
            $data['dataArray'] = $this->sessionStart();
            $category = $this->input->post('category');
            print_r($category);
            $this->load->view('dev/addApp', $data);
        }
    }

public function appImageupload()
{
    $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/appImages';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'exe';
    $config['file_type']            = 'exe';
    $config['max_size']             = 1000000000;


    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->appImageUpload('app_pic'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        print_r($error);

    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        return $data;

    }
}
```

The function appImageupoad is for uploading '.exe' files. So whenever I try to upload an executable file it gives the error. But if I change the `$config['allowed-type]` to .jpg or any image file extension then gets uploaded.

P.S.I have also tried the same thing in do_upload() it gives the same error.

Comment: see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968196/how-to-make-codeigniter-file-upload-class-accept-all-extensions and it could also be a mime type mismatch read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34622977/2275490

Comment: Thanks Vickel, It was because of mime type, not it has been solved .

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove these lines of code

`$config['file_type']            = 'exe';
$config['max_size']             = 1000000000;`

You already specified allowed types `allowed_types`
Give it a try and if works then you can apply another validations as well

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Actually, it was because of mime.php. I have to add mime type for exe